# Scanning in more than one word in C

Tags: c, char, scanf, fgets

I am trying to make a program which needs scans in more than one word, and I do not know how to do this with an unspecified length. 
My first port of call was scanf, however this only scans in one word (I know you can do scanf("%d %s",temp,temporary);, but I do not know how many words it needs), so I looked around and found fgets. One issue with this is I cannot find how to make it move to the next code, eg

```
scanf("%99s",temp);
printf("\n%s",temp);
if (strcmp(temp,"edit") == 0) {
  editloader();
}
```

would run editloader(), while:

```
fgets(temp,99,stdin);
while(fgets(temporary,sizeof(temporary),stdin))
    {
        sprintf(temp,"%s\n%s",temp,temporary);
    }   
if (strcmp(temp,"Hi There")==0) {
  editloader();
}
```

will not move onto the strcmp() code, and will stick on the original loop. What should I do instead?

Comment: I strongly suggest using POSIX 2008 `getline` function, then work on each entire line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would scan in each loop a word with scanf() and then copy it with strcpy() in the "main" string.

Comment: The only problem is that if I had a loop, would I need need to know how many words may be inputted.

Comment: `fgets(temp,99,stdin);
while(fgets(temporary,sizeof(temporary),stdin)&&(strcmp(temp,"Hi There")!=0))
    {
        sprintf(temp,"%s\n%s",temp,temporary);
    }   

  editloader();
`

So you check in the while-loop's condition if there is an input and if "Hi there" isn't in there yet.
Then

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use getline method ....I have used it in vc++ but if it exists in standard c library too then you are good to go
 check here http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/253585
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Hope you find what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I use this to read from stdin and get the same format that you would get by passing as arguments... so that you can have spaces in words and quoted words within a string.  If you want to read from a specific file, just fopen it and change the fgets line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void getargcargvfromstdin(){
char s[255], **av = (char **)malloc(255 * sizeof(char *));
unsigned char i, pos, ac;
    for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        av[i] = (char *)malloc(255 * sizeof(char));
enum quotes_t{QUOTED=0,UNQUOTED}quotes=UNQUOTED;

while (fgets(s,255,stdin)){

i=0;pos=0;ac=0;
while (i<strlen(s)) {
    /* '!'=33, 'ÿ'=-1, '¡'=-95 outside of these are non-printables */
    if ( quotes && ((s[i] < 33) && (s[i] > -1) || (s[i] < -95))){ 
        av[ac][pos] = '\0';
        if (av[ac][0] != '\0')  ac++;
        pos = 0;
    }else{
        if (s[i]=='"'){  /* support quoted strings */
            if (pos==0){
                quotes=QUOTED;
            }else{      /* support \" within strings */
                if (s[i-1]=='\\'){
                    av[ac][pos-1] = '"';
                }else{  /* end of quoted string */
                    quotes=UNQUOTED;
                }
            }
        }else{          /* printable ascii characters */
            av[ac][pos] = s[i];
            pos++;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

//your code here ac is the number of words and av is the array of words
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it exceeds the buffer size you simply can't do it.
You will have to do multiple loops

the maximum size you can scan with `scanf()` will come from

```
char *name; 
scanf("%s",name);
```

reed this

http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html